# Object references issue

Tags: c#, object, reference, null

I have two classes named `Parent` and `Child`. The `Parent` class contains a reference to the `Child` class. When I create an instance of the `Parent` class I will pass an instance of a `Child` object.

As per my knowledge we pass this `Child` instance as reference. Then I cache this `Parent` object in an external cache. Then I retrieve this object from another system. I think in that system the instance of the `Child` object may not be present.

As per theory '_child' contains reference of object in the heap not the actual object am i right?

Just think in server farm scenario, your object instance should be available to other system and the system once generated that object

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child _child = null;

    public Parent(Child c)
    {
        _child=c;   
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name;
}

static void Main()
{
    Child c = new Child();
    c.Name="vivek";
    Parent p = Parent(c);
    string key = ExternalCache.Add(p);
}
```

Now what will happen if I try to retrieve this `Parent` object in another system or application?

```
static void Main()
{
   Parent p = (Parent)ExternalCache.Get(Key)
   Console.WriteLine(p._child.Name);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C# code.

Comment: "I think in that system the instance of the child object may not be present" Is it present or not? You seem to be asking a question which you are able to answer yourself by investigating your own system.

Comment: Where did You got `ExternalCache` object?

Comment: Did you try to compile this program? If so, what compiler errors did you get? If there are no compiler errors, could you post the exact code that you are using?

Comment: hi this is some theory concept, Not actual code

Comment: When you provide "theory concept", please provide code that actually works. Otherwise it's too hard to tell the difference between what's actually wrong or where you've just made mistakes in uncompilable code samples. It doesn't need to be the actual code, just code that has the problem you're facing, and code that is correct.

Comment: if i cache the instance of Parent in some external object cache and retrieve it in another system, what will be the reference of child.

Comment: What would be this "*other system*"?

Comment: As per theory '_child' contains reference of object in the heap not the actual object am i right?

Comment: @James other computer, i am discussing this on the base of a server farm scenario

Comment: serialize the objects for later use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to pass the same *references* of objects to different machines simply because they won't be running within the same memory space so even if you could the references wouldn't be any use. However, what you can do is serialize the object graph & re-contruct the object at the other end - this is known as **object serialization**, or just **serialization** in general.

The .NET Framework has various built-in serializers which allow different types of serialization e.g.

- Xml - [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx),  [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)
- JSON - [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)